# Issue when executing a batch file in c# using wmi

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to execute a batch file on a remote machine after a button click happens.
The executed batch file kills a process on the remote computer via port number and then restarts it.

While my code works and the batch file is executed, the process is killed but it can't relaunch it because the process is still running under a different owner.
Turns out the owner has changed from the local admin, to my account.
So while it did kill the process it thinks it's still running in the background.

Since I know for a fact the batch file always works as intended, I know it has to be my code.
Any help would be appreciated or if there is a more efficient way of doing this, that would also be welcomed advice.

It's also worth noting that I can append a 1,2,3 or 9 after the batch file to call a specific process to be killed. In this case it's process 1.

Here is my C# code:

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Management.ConnectionOptions connOptions =
                new System.Management.ConnectionOptions();

            connOptions.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;

            string compName = BxIP.Text;
            System.Management.ManagementScope manScope =
                new System.Management.ManagementScope(
                    String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", compName), connOptions);
            manScope.Connect();

            System.Management.ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions =
                new System.Management.ObjectGetOptions();

            System.Management.ManagementPath managementPath =
                new System.Management.ManagementPath("Win32_Process");

            System.Management.ManagementClass processClass =
                new System.Management.ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

            System.Management.ManagementBaseObject inParams =
                processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");

            inParams["CommandLine"] = @"c:\app\batch\RestartApps.bat 1";

            System.Management.ManagementBaseObject outParams =
                processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
        }
```

Comment: Update: I believe I found the issue to be it's running the batch file and thus starting the process under my personal credentials instead of local admin. How can I code this to have it "run as"?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's interested, I found I cannot run the batch file as a certain user using WMI.
I ended up using the Process command. Code is below.

```
                     Process process = new Process();
                     string localDestinationFolderPath = @"c:\app\batch\";
                     string call = localDestinationFolderPath + "RestartApps.bat 1";
                     string user = "User";
                     string pass = "Pass";
                     process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\PsExec.exe";
                     process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" \\" + BxIP.Text + " -i -u " + user + " -p " + pass + " " + call;
                     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                     process.Start();
                     process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```